# Is it possible to get fields of Transform type in Unity using reflection?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

This code in any MonoBehaviour script doesn't cause 'asd' to store transform fields:

```
var asd = transform.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

This on any other type created by me would cause 'asd' to store array of private and public properties of that type.

Hence, what is the difference of my new type and Transform?

Are there some BindingFlags that i should add?

Comment: Your code is asking for fields *of* the `Transform` class, not fields that *are* the `Transform` type.

Comment: Yes, is that wrong? Can't i have fields of Transform class stored in 'asd'?

Comment: I said nothing about `asd`, I said that your question ("fields of Type `Transform`") does not match your code ("fields of the `Transform` Type"). That is, the difference between `private Transform widget;` and `class Transform { private string widget;` })